# Lavravel route url not displaying correct results from db

Tags: php, url, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I'm trying to pass the getMonth view via the route but doens't seem be working as it shows all results from my db when the $month is specified instead of filtering the results by month. However $id does work and will go to a single post matching the $id from the db.

```
Route::get('blog', ['as' => 'blog', 'uses' => 'BlogController@BlogIndex']);
Route::get('blog/{Id}', ['as' => 'blog.id', 'uses' => 'BlogController@ShowbyId']);
Route::get('blog/month/{month}', ['as' => 'blog.month', 'uses' => 'BlogController@ShowbyMonth']);

class BlogController extends BaseController {

 public function BlogIndex()
{
 //get the posts from the database by asking the Active Record for "all"
$blogs = Blog::all();
$blogs = DB::table('blogs')->paginate(3);
// and create a view which we return - note dot syntax to go into folder
return View::make('pages.blog', array('blogs' => $blogs));
}
public function ShowbyId($Id)
{          
   $Ids = Blog::where('Id', '=', $Id)->get();
// show the view with blog posts (app/views/pages/blog.blade.php)
return View::make('pages.blog')
    ->with('Ids', $Ids)      
}
public function ShowbyMonth($month)
{
   $months = Blog::where('month', '=', $month)->get();
// show the view with blog posts (app/views/pages/blog.blade.php)
return View::make('pages.blog')
    ->with('months', $months)     
}
}
```

blog.blade.php

```
@if(isset($blogs)) 
@foreach ($blogs as $blog)
  <div class="blog-outer-wrap">
  <img src="images/blog/{{ $blog->img}}"> 
  <div class="blog-header">{{ $blog->header }}</div>
  <div class="blog-text">{{ $blog->content }}</div>
  <a href="{{ URL::route('blog.slug', [$blog->slug]) }}">
  </div>
@endforeach
@elseif(isset($Ids)) 
@foreach ($Ids as $Id)
  <div class="blog-outer-wrap">
  <img src="images/blog/{{ $Id->img}}"> 
  <div class="blog-header">{{ $Id->header }}</div>
  <div class="blog-text">{{ $Id->content }}</div>
  </div>
 @elseif(isset($months))
 @foreach ($months as $month) 
<div class="blog-outer-wrap">
<img src="images/blog/{{ $Month->img}}"> 
 <div class="blog-header">{{ $Month->header }}</div>
<div class="blog-text">{{ $Month->content }}</div>
</div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: What other routes for `blog` have you defined in routes? Does it goes to `showByMonth` function?

Comment: Sorry just updated the routes, yes it goes to ShowbyMonth and ShowbyID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it solves the problem but in blade file you have:

```
@elseif(isset($months))
 @foreach ($months as $month) 
<div class="blog-outer-wrap">
<img src="images/blog/{{ $Month->img}}"> 
 <div class="blog-header">{{ $Month->header }}</div>
<div class="blog-text">{{ $Month->content }}</div>
</div>
@endif
```

and it should be rather:

```
@elseif(isset($months))
 @foreach ($months as $Month) 
<div class="blog-outer-wrap">
<img src="images/blog/{{ $Month->img}}"> 
 <div class="blog-header">{{ $Month->header }}</div>
<div class="blog-text">{{ $Month->content }}</div>
</div>
@endif
```

You should care about variables case.

Comment: thanks I'll make sure the cases match. I think the problem is more to do with the routing though

Comment: @tomharrison But you told earlier it goes to correct route. I don't see any problem with routing here

Comment: $id goes to correct route and displays post by id but $month displays all db results and doesn't filter by month so it's not picking up the variable presumably it's getting confused in the routing

Comment: @tomharrison And what exactly url you use to display it by month?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is your URI/route structure, you currently have this:

```
Route::get('blog/{Id}', ['as' => 'blog.id', 'uses' => 'BlogController@ShowbyId']);
Route::get('blog/month/{month}', ['as' => 'blog.month', 'uses' => 'BlogController@ShowbyMonth']);
```

Whenever you try to access the `blog.month` route `blog.id` is receiving the word `month`. It may be better to put the month route first, so that the month URI is hit before the ID route.

```
Route::get('blog/month/{month}', ['as' => 'blog.month', 'uses' => 'BlogController@ShowbyMonth']);
Route::get('blog/{id}', ['as' => 'blog.id', 'uses' => 'BlogController@ShowbyId']);
```

---

Also, to clean up your controller you may consider using a query scope to make your logic more reusable and easier to debug. In your model you could do something like this:

```
class Blog extends Eloquent {
  public function scopeMonth($query, $month) {
    return $query->where('month', '=', $month);
  }
}
```

Then in your Controller you could do this:

```
class BlogController extends BaseController {

  //.. BlogIndex here

  public function ShowbyId($Id)
  {          
     $blog = Blog::find($id)->get();

    // show the view with blog posts (app/views/pages/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('pages.blog')
      ->with('Ids', $blog);      
  }

  public function ShowbyMonth($month)
  {
    $months = Blog::month($month)->get();

    // show the view with blog posts (app/views/pages/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('pages.blog')
      ->with('months', $months)     
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps!